# Display error property when a bad request error happens in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to send the field that caused the error in the request reason of a `Bad Request` error to the client.

For example user must be sent `string TravelDate`, but it send me the `Date TravelDate`, I want say to client this file `TravelDate` has problems, you must send `string` not `Date`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: good question Kia Kia!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement `IValidatableObject` in the model class, as shown in the following example:

```
public class Test: IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TravelDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        bool isDateTime = false;

        isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(TravelDate, out dateTime);
        if (isDateTime)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult($"TravelDate should be a string",new[] { "TravelDate" });
        }
    }
}
```

**For asp.net core 3.0**,you need to be sure add `[ApiController]` in your Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> Post(Test machines)
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Beautiful answer Rena!

Comment: Beautiful solution! for advanced usage

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

This will send back to the client all the validation errors that have occurred.

In this structure:-

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "|4f2a9400-4d321f2c7fffdb9f.",
"errors": {
    "xxxx": [
        "The value 'xxxsdsd' is not valid."
    ]
}
```

Then you can read the errors value and show it to the user.

Comment: its not work man . it show me this `message: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails"`

Comment: when i send a request adn have a model and it have a bad request it not go into the controller